# User defined function is "suspended" state is this normal?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

We have a user defined function created some time ago which shows as "suspended" status for over a week from:

```
USE master
SELECT  *
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests  
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
ORDER BY start_time
```

The row from the query above has "status" as "suspended" and continues to increment values for each of:

```
cpu_time    
210262625
total_elapsed_time
623982642    
reads
741700958   
reads
19754
logical_reads
2938802909
```

I have previously killed the SPID when it reached 37 billion `logical_reads` but it is used very often and of course showed right back up and started this same pattern.

My question is really in two parts.

**First, is this normal behavior for a heavily used user defined function to see it in suspended state?**

**Second, how can I tell how many times a user defined function is called? (and potendially what called it**)

As a side note, I am not really pleased with the function and how it was written however unless this is "totally abnormal" behavior I don't have time to rewrite it at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. If your function has been running continuously for ten minutes while
   showing a suspended state, I would use your first query and check the
   following columns: `wait_type`, `wait_time`, `last_wait_type`, and
   `wait_resource`.
2. To determine how many times the function has been called, use the
   first query to capture the function's plan_handle. Then use the system view `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` to get the usecount.

For example:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) AS db, 
    OBJECT_NAME(objectid) AS objName, 
    usecounts, 
    size_in_bytes, 
    cacheobjtype
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
WHERE plan_handle = 0x05000700A77A001140A10585000000000000000000000000
```

It sounds like the function is either being executed within some kind of loop or else processing a massive amount of data.

To check for all the locations which could be calling the function from within the database:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS objectName
FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE definition LIKE '%[function_name]%'
```

Comment: This was a useful answer - turns out the function is called from user activity but also from a SQL agent job - in different ways, and the agent job hangs, still have to dig into why but it got me a target for my "ninja sql query killer saber attack" (now say that 5 times really fast )